# Python feedparser Module cannot append data into a dictionary

Tags: python, rss

I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
I am trying to store all of the entry values in one dict as I have created a function:

```
rss_url = 'https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/' + league + '/news'
    parser = feedparser.parse(rss_url)

    newsInfo = {
        'title': None,
        'link': None,
        'description': None,
        'image': None
    }

    for entry in parser.entries:
        newsInfo['title'].append(entry.title)
        newsInfo['link'].append(entry.links[0].href)
        newsInfo['description'].append(entry.description)
        newsInfo['image'].append(entry.content[0].value)
    
    return newsInfo
```

However on the line where I use `.append` I am getting a NoneType Error.

bonus question: if I render the values from the feedparser onto HTML will it display the news correctly, or will there be another step?

Comment: can you show where `newsInfo` comes from? Some key of it has None as value

Comment: @WilliSattler Check recent edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want to init them as lists:

```
newsInfo = {
    'title': [],
    'link': [],
    'description': [],
    'image': []
}
```

or you want to assign the values in the for loop (depending on your use case):

```
for entry in parser.entries:
    newsInfo['title'] = entry.title
    newsInfo['link'] = entry.links[0].href
    newsInfo['description'] = entry.description
    newsInfo['image'] = entry.content[0].value
```

Comment: The first one was what I needed, thanks. Also if I were to render newsInfo in HTML would it display correctly?

Comment: RSS feeds usually use XML to pass their data and only want to give a short discription or headline on a topic. Have a look on the RSS feed [XML file](https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/nhl/news) and what you get with `feedparser`. So, you will probably have to add another step to form it into HTML.
Are you using a webserver like flask, django or somethin like that?

Comment: I am using flask and I was able to send the data to my HTML file. If I just print out the dictionary like this: {{ nhl }} I see all of the correct data. However if I try to format it like this: <h1>{{ row.title }}</h1> a pointer to where the data is stored is displayed, rather than the data itself

Comment: Can you show where `row` comes from? But I guess you need to access it with an index like `{{row.title[0]}}`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Q87b7YQn That's what my code looks like. nhl, nba, nfl, and mlb are just the names of the different sources

Comment: If you have passed in the render function `nhl=newsfunction` for example, than you would access the titles in the template files like `{{nhl['title']}}` , which will be a list.

Comment: Thanks for helping me in the right direction. I was able to do it by turning my variable into a list of dictionaries.